# Is there a way to force traffic comin from www.abc.com to go to abc.com via htaccess or dns?

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain

I am having some trouble with a flash file that has hardcoded urls in it.  The flash loads fine if I visit from abc.com.  But if I try to view it from www.abc.com it wont load.

So my question is, how do I got about forcing all traffic, including that coming from www.abc.com to be directed to abc.com instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use, in conjunction with apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module.  It's domain-agnostic.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i think i will end up using this one since i can use this code regardless of what the domain is. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look into `mod_alias` if you're running Apache, which I'll assume because you talk about .htaccess. A directive similar to

```
RedirectMatch http://www.abc.com(.*)$ http://abc.com$1
```

might do some good.

Comment: so which method is better or more appropriate?  Or does it matter?

Comment: Both will work. Use whichever one you're more comfortable with.